# Ubuntu 14.04 + LibreOffice 4.2 spell-checker dictionaries don't come up

Tags: libreoffice, language-support, dictionary, spell-checking

I want to use 3 spell-checkers in LibreOffice 4.2:

English (en-gb) 
German (de-de) 
French (fr-fr)

My Ubuntu and LibreOffice standard language is English (UK).

The Extention Manager in LibreOffice shows that the German and French spell-checkers are installed. Also, all three languages have the tick mark under Tools -> Options -> Language settings -> Default languages for documents

However, in the spell-checker menu (at the bottom in the middle when you have a blank Writer document) neither German nor French appears. Only English UK is shown.

As a workaround to get at least English and German to work, I set up German as default language for documents LibreOffice.

So that I can choose between German and English. However, I couldn't manage to have French shown in that list too.

Any ideas of how to solve this issue?

Unfortunately, yet I'm not allowed to post screen shots because I don't have 10 credits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *easiest way* to have multiple languages installed on the system is to go to the system settings and then install the languages you're interested in there.  All the other applications will follow suit (like you'll also have the same spell-checker in `firefox`, `gedit`, `libre-office`, ...

The *disadvantage* of the easy way is that it will also install help files for those languages...

There is also the *hard way* to do this, but most users aren't interested in the hard way.  ;-)

Comment: And as you're a reputation 1 user: don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, therefore "accepting" the answer, which is better then saying "thank you" as both of our reputations will go up!  ;-)

Comment: And drop me a comment @Fabby if *you are interested in the hard way*!  :P

Comment: Hi Fabby! 

Many thanks for your answer. I installed those extra languages in Ubuntu but LibreOffice hasn't updated its language status. I need to uninstall with apt-get remove hunspell/aspell etc. ?  ..As said, the German spelling checker is working

Comment: Have you tried an `apt-get upgrade` after that?

Comment: Hi Fabby, I'm interested in the 'hard way' as I need to learn more commands anyway. So, in case you have the answer already ready, feel free to post it. Also, I would like to keep my Ubuntu system clean and neat and the 'hard way' may allow for this.

Comment: one word: `aptitude` Its a TUI (Text UI) front-end to the repository.  [RTFM](http://aptitude.alioth.debian.org/doc/en/) first!  ;-)